# Comparing Multiple Dates to Identify Duplicate Records in a Database

Tags: teradata

I checked and found a TON of threads of finding duplicate records, but not any that specifically addressed a date comparison.

I am attempting to use JOIN to identify where there are similar records in a database. Some of these records have the same values in certain fields, but not all. So I ALSO want to consider dates that are the same or have a variance of +1 or +2 from the other records.

So my definition of 'duplicate' is that the Color_Type, ID_Type, and Category_Cd are all the same, and the Activity_Date must be within 0-2 days difference from similar records.

Example:

```
**Record 1** has a 
Activity_Date of '10/25/2021' 
Color_Type of 'Blue' 
ID_Type as '1234' Category_Cd of 'Rainbow' 
Txn_ID of '1A2B'

**Record 2** has a 
Activity_Date of '10/24/2021' 
Color_Type of 'Blue' 
ID_Type as '1234' 
Category_Cd of 'Rainbow' 
Txn_ID of '3C4D'

**Record 3** has a 
Activity_Date of '10/26/2021' 
Color_Type of 'Blue' 
ID_Type as '1234' 
Category_Cd of 'Rainbow' 
Txn_ID of '5E6F'

**Record 4** has a 
Activity_Date of '09/01/2021' 
Color_Type of 'Blue' 
ID_Type as '1234' 
Category_Cd of 'Rainbow' 
Txn_ID of '7G8H'

**Record 5** has a 
Activity_Date of '10/25/2021' 
Color_Type of 'Blue' 
ID_Type as '1234' 
Category_Cd of 'Rainbow' 
Txn_ID of '9I0J'
```

I want my query to return records 1, 2, 3 and 5, but NOT return record 4

Here is my query which works on finding duplicates, but returns records which are similar but not considering the date difference I want.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
    FROM DATABASETABLE.DATABASEVIEW
    WHERE ACTIVTY_DT GE '2021-10-01'
    ) dupa  
JOIN 
    (SELECT ID_Type, Color_Type, Category_Cd, 
            COUNT (*) AS postings
    FROM DATABASETABLE.DATABASEVIEW
    WHERE ACTIVTY_DT GE '2021-10-01'
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
    HAVING postings = 2) dupb

    ON  dupa.ID_Type = dupb.ID_Type AND
        dupa.Color_Type = dupb.Color_Type AND
        dupa.Category_Cd = dupb.Category_Cd

ORDER BY dupa.ID_Type
```

Really new (and self taught) to SQL, so any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!!

Comment: That query cannot work, remove the last AND from the last ON clause

Comment: And there is no `ACTIVTY_DT` column mentioned in you description of the tables

Comment: I am using Teradata. I see that when I created my question the form automatically populated the mysql tag. I'll update.

Comment: `Activity_Date must be within 0-2 days difference from similar records` - this is not clear.  Within 2 days of the earliest record returned? From the previous row (based on activity_date)?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be your logic based on *Windowed Aggregates*:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DATABASETABLE.DATABASEVIEW
WHERE ACTIVTY_DT >= DATE '2021-10-01'
QUALIFY -- current date within two days of previous date
   ACTIVTY_DT - 2
   <= 
   lag(ACTIVTY_DT)  -- prev date
   over (partition by ID_Type, Color_Type, Category_Cd -- same values in all three columns
         order by ACTIVTY_DT) 
or   -- similar condition against next row to get both rows retunrd
   ACTIVTY_DT + 2
   >= 
   lead(ACTIVTY_DT) -- next date
   over (partition by ID_Type, Color_Type, Category_Cd -- same values in all three columns
         order by ACTIVTY_DT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible answer using good old subqueries:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM DATABASETABLE.DATABASEVIEW dupa
WHERE dupa.ACTIVITY_DT GE '2021-10-01'
    and (select count(*) 
         from DATABASETABLE.DATABASEVIEW dupb
         where  dupb.ACTIVITY_DT GE '2021-10-01'
                dupa.ID_Type = dupb.ID_Type AND
                dupa.Color_Type = dupb.Color_Type AND
                dupa.Category_Cd = dupb.Category_Cd AND
                ABS(dupa.ACTIVITY_DT - dupb.ACTIVITY_DT) <= 2
        ) > 1
```

For each record in dupa we count the records in dupb with the same Id_Type, Color_type, Category_cd, and activity_dt is allowed to have up to two days difference, if the number of records satisfying this is greater than 1 then we return this dupa row (the subquery also counts the dupa record itself, its result is  always >=1)